# Solutions of complex linear difference equations

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, recurrence-relations, meromorphic-functions

I know solutions of complex linear differential equations like
\begin{equation}
f^{(k+1)}(z)+c_{k-1} f^{(k)}(z)+\ldots+c_1 f^{\prime}(z)+c_0=0
\end{equation}
are linear combinations of $e^{\alpha z}$. and I'm wondering what the solutions of complex linear difference equations like
\begin{equation}
f(z+\eta_1)+f(z+\eta_2)+\ldots+f(z+\eta_n)=0,\ \ \  \eta_1 \cdots\eta_n \in \mathbf{C}
\end{equation}
look like. It seems easy when $\eta_i$ are all integers, but I don't know the general case.

If we cannot get the exact form of solutions, can we get the order?

**remark.** the order of a meromorphic function is define to be $\rho(f) = \overline{\lim}\frac{\log T(r,f)}{\log r}$, where $T(r,f)$ represents the Nevanlinna characteristic of $f(z)$. If $f(z)$ is an entire function, $\rho(f) = \overline{\lim} \frac{\log\log M(r,f)}{\log r}$ where $M(r,f) = \sup_{|z| < r} f(z).$